# архитектура periscope

Tags: java, android, архитектура

Подскажите, как устроена работа сервиса periscope. С помощью каких технологий идет передача потокового видео.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть доклад от [Periscope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjC3ZKYG74g), в котором упоминаются:

- стриминг сервер от Wowza Media Systems
- algolia для поиска и индексирования
- iron.io для батчинга
- PubNub для чата